# webservice issue while consuming asmx webservice by php server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services

**The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' var IsFormValidated='T';**

getting this error while consuming .please help

i have tried below code in my webconfig

still getting below errors::::
**OPTIONS http://xyz.com/WebService1.asmx/Login 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min%201.4.4.js:141
OPTIONS http://xyz.com/WebService1.asmx/Login Origin http://xyz.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery.min%201.4.4.js:141
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xyz.com/WebService1.asmx/Login. Origin http://xyz.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Default.aspx:1**

Comment: Have you tried browse the service url in browser?. Refer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b72d695-5790-4615-99cd-4e331d7e864d/wcf-returning-the-content-type-texthtml-of-the-response-message-does-not-match-the-content-type-of

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx

Comment: its not a rest api web service

Comment: You can download WCF test client tool and check whether you are able to consume the service  http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2009/02/23/info-running-wcftestclient-tool-in-a-pc-without-vs-net-2008.aspx  http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/guillermo/Code/WcfTestClient.zip

Comment: i am using asmx websevice not wcf

Answer (score 0):

First build a working c# client. then compare the request it sends (header + body) to the request your php client sends.

Comment: if this error is with the c# client then turn on tracing and logging to see details